# New to Keras, massive amounts of memory Conv2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My understanding from a convolution neural network is it is a set of smaller filters that applies over an image.

So a Conv2D like in the simple model below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(101,101,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(101*101,activation='sigmoid'))
```

parameter = 128*3*3 = 8192
byte count = parameters*4 =  32768 bytes

The reality i'm seeing is that tensorflow my backend is trying to allocate 12.5GB of video memory for this training.

My data is being passed to it as a (4000,101,101,1) array like in the MNIST examples which used a (60000,28,28,1) array. The data for my whole array converted to floats is ~326MB.

Am I doing something wrong or is it near impossible to train images on GPU without literally 10's of GB of video ram? I have 8 GB and am not expecting to create something world changing, but the numbers. Do I need to prep my data differently? I tried passing half the data and the memory allocation was basically the same, but changing the filter count to 30 lets me compile with no errors. Am I misunderstanding the parameters? Any assistance would be appreciated.

I thought 128 was the total number of filters. Is it the Depth of the filters, not the total number of kernels per pass? Read the documentation and still think i'm missing something.

Comment: By default TensorFlow allocates all GPU memory and manages it internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is awfully big:

```
model.add(Flatten())  #shape: (batch, 128*50*50)
model.add(Dense(101*101,activation='sigmoid')) #parameters: 128*50*50*101*101 + 101*101 = 3264330201
```

THREE BILLION parameters. (Check your `model.summary()` to confirm)

You're applying a dense layer to everything with the flatten: channels * pixels * pixels.

I suggest you look for U-net style models (fully convolutional).
Or if you do want to use dense layers, use some kind of [GlobalPooling](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/) first.

---

Summary:

```
input:    shape: (101,101,1)      params: 0
conv:     shape: (99, 99, 128)    params: 3*3*1*128 + 3*3*128
pool:     shape: (50,50, 128)     params: 0
flat:     shape: (50*50*128,)     params: 0
dense:    shape: (101*101,)       params: 50*50*128*101*101 + 101*101
```

Comment: hm where are the 50's coming from? I don't think I understand that?

I thought the parameters were corresponding to 128*3*3. What am I missing?

Comment: You're talking about the parameters of the "convolutional" layer. I'm talking about the parameters of the `Dense` layer. You have an image, 50x50x128 as input for it.

Comment: ah much appreciated. I understand now. I didn't realize how pool shrunk the data. I thought it  was going down to 3*3128/(2*2). Not 99*99*128/(2*2)  I didn't realize I was preserving so many parameters. Thanks!